# How to use onlick to change font in iterated array of divs?

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have an array that I iterate through in order to place text in separate divs on a web page (later on I animate the divs).  I want to add an onclick to each div, so when the div/text is clicked, the font weight changes.  I know at least one way to use an onclick in a simpler situation:

```
<div class="nameDiv" id="div1" onclick='boldText(this, this.id);'>Test</div>

<script>
function boldText(txt, txtid){
    var el = document.getElementById(txtid);
    var fontstyle = window.getComputedStyle(el, null).fontWeight;

    if (fontstyle != '800') {
    txt.style.fontWeight = '800';
  } else {
    txt.style.fontWeight = '300';
  }

}
</script>
```

However, I'm unable to get this same type of thing working in my code with the iterating.

```
var setNames = function() {
    var h = 0;
    for(var n = 0; n < numberStudents; n++){   
        var divName = "floatName" + n;
        var names = nameArray[n].fields.nickname;  <!-- gets the text/name for each div -->
        var divTag = document.createElement('div');
        divTag.id = divName;
        divTag.innerHTML = names;
        divTag.className = "randomFloat";

        // try to give each div an onclick
        divTag.onclick = boldText(this, this.id);

        studentCol.appendChild(divTag); <!-- attach to studentCol/'anchor'/parent element -->
        };
    };

setNames();

function boldText(txt, txtid){  <!--  pass both the object and the object id -->
    var el = document.getElementById(txtid);   

    // I've tried both lines below -->
    var fontstyle = window.getComputedStyle(el, null).fontWeight; <!-- gives me an error saying el is not an object -->

    //var fontstyle = window.getComputedStyle(el, null).fontWeight;
    // line above gives TypeError: Argument 1 of Window.getComputedStyle does not implement interface Element -->

    if (fontstyle != '300') {
        txt.style.fontWeight = '300';
    } else {
        txt.style.fontWeight = '800';
    }

};
```

Is it possible that each divTag.id can have a separate onclick?  If so, what do I need to change in my code?

Comment: Why do you think you need to pass both `this` and `this.id` to the function? If you just pass `this`, the function can use `txt.id` to get the ID if it needs it.

Comment: And there's no need to call `getElementById`, since the element is the same as `txt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are assigning the `boldText` function result and not the function itself. Please try this:

```
divTag.onclick = boldText;
```

In this way you can access `this` inside `boldText` function, no need to pass any arguments to it. E.g.

```
this.style.fontWeight = '300';
```

Comment: Can the function also somehow return a value?  For example, can function boldText() return a value which saves the state of the font weight?